# Skip Rows in Column Sum in Excel using C#

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I am trying to calculate the column sum by skipping specific rows with excel interop in C#.i am not able to figure out how to do that please help. I want to sum highlighted rows and skip the others in the attached image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Excel array indices are generally 1-based, not 0-based (i.e. lowest element is number 1).

```
var xl = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
var b = xl.Workbooks.Open("C:\\Junk\\Junk.xlsx");
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet s = b.Worksheets[1]; //1-based
var r = s.Range["A1", "E4"];
int sum = 0;
for (var row = 1; row <= 4; row += 2)
{
    sum += r.Value2[row, 1]; //also 1-based
}            
xl.Quit();
```

Comment: You've changed your question since I wrote this answer. To solve your new question, you will need to change to row++ increment in the loop and introduce an `if` statement inside the loop to check the column A value